# Jest configuration with multiple moduleNameMapper

Tags: nest, ts-jest

I have a requirement where I need to map my libs as an expanded path in the Jest config moduleNameMapper configuration.

Along with that I also need to provide one axois as the name module mapping.

How can I do both in the moduleNameMapper in jest-e2e.js?

Here is my existing `jest-e2e.js` file:

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('../../../tsconfig.json');

module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "ts"],
  verbose: true,
  rootDir: '.',
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testRegex: ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '"<rootDir>/../../../' }),
};
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "paths": {
      "@app/logger": [
        "libs/logger/src"
      ],
   }
}
```

I want to add one more moduleNameMapping which is not there in the `tsconfig.json`.

Basically, I want to add this mapping as well:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
  }
```

How may I combine both the stuffs into the same `moduleNameMapper` clause in the jest config file.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('../../../tsconfig.json');

const libNameMapping = pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '"<rootDir>/../../../' });

module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "ts"],
  verbose: true,
  rootDir: '.',
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testRegex: ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
    ...libNameMapping,
  },
};
```

So basically how can both the axios and the nameMapping can be combined and applied to the `moduleNameMapper` portion of the configuration. That's the query here.

Now if I want to add it like without any helper, like below, it also does not work:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
    '^@app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../../../libs/$1/src',
  },
```

The path are not resolved, gives this error:

```
    Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @app/common/const mapped as:
    C:\Users\<>\clients\<>\<>\<>\<>\nest-services\libs\$1\src.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@app\/(.*)$/": "C:\Users\<>\clients\<>\<>\<>\<>\nest-services\libs\$1\src"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

      1 | import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
    > 2 | import { constants } from '@app/common/const';
```

I think I have to use the Jest helper method. But how can I do it combining both axois and my `libs` name mapping, is not getting it.